# AttributeError: 'Style' object has no attribute 'fg_gc'

Tags: python, gtk, drawable, graphicscontext, drawingarea

i'm working on a Gtk.DrawingArea because i want simply draw a rectangle.
I've cut and pasted the example of DrawingArea from Gtk examples, cutting off useless code for my purpose.

Here below the code (don't care about indentation problems, it's all ok, Geany IDE sucks):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')



class collega_GUI:



    def __init__(self):

            self.__builder = Gtk.Builder()
            self.__builder.add_from_file('prova.glade')

            self.__area = self.__builder.get_object('drawingarea1')

            self.__style = self.__area.get_style()
            self.__gc = self.__style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
            self.__pangolayout = self.__area.create_pango_layout("")
            self.__area.draw_rectangle(self.__gc, True, 0, 0, 20, 20)

            self.__pangolayout.set_text("1")
            self.__area.draw_layout(self.gc, 0, 50, self.__pangolayout)

            self.__window = self.__builder.get_object('window1')
            self.__window.show()


if __name__=='__main__':
    prova = collega_GUI()
    Gtk.main()
```

So the python interpreter says me:

> AttributeError: 'Style' object has no attribute 'fg_gc'

Please help me, i've read the documentation at (http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-DrawingAreaWidgetAndDrawing.html) but i can't find the error

Comment: i'm really interested why some1 has downvoted the question..

Comment: Would it be possible for you to fix the indentation. I think the next thing for you to do is to find out what type `self.__style` is, and what attributes it has.

Comment: I can't edit the code, because it would reply me it isn't correctly formatted. **type(self.__style) -> gi.repository.Gtk.Style**

Comment: Try harder. Please fix indentation. Did you do the debugging I suggested?

Comment: It seems it has just the **fg** attribute

Comment: Now it raises another error: **AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'STATE_NORMAL'**. But man, look at the example of Gtk about GtkDrawingArea linked above.. it works.. why doesn't it happen in mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your imports should look like this:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
```

You are mixing the `pygtk` wrapper and the `gi.introspection` bindings which are two different things! And potentially even mixing `gtk2` with `gtk3` widgets!

---

Also keep in mind: **that tutorial's last update was in 2005**!

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the support on this topic and the one about GtkGrid, because they were strictly related.